# JQuery get attr value from ajax loaded page

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my index.php I've a ajax pager that load a content page (paginator.php).

index.php

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/paginator.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/functions.js'></script>
<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<html>
<div id="content"></div>
```

paginator.js

```
$(function() {

  var pageurl = 'paginator.php';

  //Initialise the table at the first run
  $( '#content' ).load( pageurl, { pag: 1 }, function()
  {
    //animation();
  });

  //Page navigation click
  $( document ).on( 'click', 'li.goto', function() 
  {
    //Get the id of clicked li
    var pageNum = $( this ).attr( 'id' );
    $( '#content' ).load( pageurl, { pag: pageNum }, function() 
    {
        //animation();
    });
  });

}); /* END */
```

paginator.php

```
<ul><li>..etc </ul>
...
...
<a id='test' vid='123'>get the id</a>

<a id='test2' url='somepage.php'>open fancybox</a>
```

I would like to take a variable of the loaded page (paginator.php) in this way but unfortunately I can not.

functions.js

```
$(function() {

   $('#test' ).click(function(e)
   {
     var id = $('#test').attr('vid');
     alert ("vid is " + vid);
   });

}); /* END */
```

In this case popup not appear.

I tried with add fancybox in my functions.js. Dialog box appear but the url attr is not taken.

```
 var url = $('#test2').attr('url');

 $('#test').fancybox({
   'href'              : url,
   'width'             : 100,
   'height'            : 100,
   'autoScale'         : false,
   'transitionIn'      : 'none',
   'transitionOut'     : 'none',
   'type'              : 'iframe',
   'fitToView'     : true,
   'autoSize'          : false
 });
```

In other scenarios, without having the page loaded, I can do it, but in this case the behavior is different. How could I do this? thanks

EDIT

my goal is to open a dialog (fancybox) taking a variable from the loaded page

EDIT2

I tried in this way

paginator.php

```
<a id="test" vid="1234">click me</a>
```

paginator.js

```
//Initialise the table at the first run
$( '#content' ).load( pageurl, { pag: 1 }, function()
{
    hide_anim();
    popup();
});

//Page navigation click
$( document ).on( 'click', 'li.goto', function() 
{
    //Get the id of clicked li
    var pageNum = $( this ).attr( 'id' );
    $( '#content' ).load( pageurl, { pag: pageNum }, function() 
    {
        hide_anim();
        popup();
    });
})
```

function.js

```
function popup() {
  $('#test' ).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var vid = $('#test').attr('vid');
  alert ("vid is " + vid);
  });
}
```

But popup not appear...

Comment: Why don't you delegate event as you are already doing it for other elements `'li.goto'`? Anyway, `id='#test'` should be `id='test'` in HTML markup.

Comment: You haven't declared `vid` anywhere it's `id` instead of `vid`!

Comment: or simply put the contents of the *paginator.php* using the selector html function like so
`$('#content').html('put the contents here as string');`

Comment: @A.Wolff It's a fancy popup! so `#` may be a required!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak so then selector is not correct, should be: `'#\\#test'`

Comment: I edit my script. I've an error in id=#test and id=#test2

Comment: most likely the content isn't loaded yet. You have to go into the pagination.js load() function and define a success callback. in the success callback you can define another function like alertVid(). And inside your function.js wrap the click event in a function alertVid()... also make sure function.js is loaded before pagination.js inside your dom

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$('#test' ).click(function(e){});
```

won't work for AJAX loaded HTML.

As @A.Wodff said, you should use event delegation. Try this:

```
$('document').on('click', '#test', function(){
    var id = $('#test').attr('vid');
    alert ("vid is " + id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/functions.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/paginator.js'></script>
```

Paginator.js

```
$( '#content' ).load( pageurl, { pag: 1 }, function() {
    //if load complete
    yourFunctionName();
});
```

function.js

```
function yourFunctionName() {
  $(document).on('click', '#test', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var vid = $('#test').attr('vid');
    alert ("vid is " + vid);
  });
}
```

This will make sure the content is loaded before you try to access it. In your case you don't have it inside your dom when you try to access #test / vid.

Comment: did you put the function.js before the paginator.js in your html js include?

Comment: Yes I put function.js before paginator.js

Comment: In firebug I see ReferenceError: popup is not defined (popup is myfunction name)

Comment: thats because the js file where popup is defined is not placed before your paginator.js file.

Comment: I defined popup function in my function.js file as you suggested. I defined call to popup function in my load function in my paginator.js.I put functions.js BEFORE pagination.js as you suggested, but unfortunately I still get that error... :(

Comment: I resolve putting the func popup() in file functions.js out of jquery $(function()... 
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem and I know this question have a lot of years, but I find a working solution for this problem:

```js
$('body').on('click','#test',function() {
  var ref = $(this).attr('vid');            
  alert ("vid is " + ref);
});
```

This works fine for me on ajax call and get the attr value